# Can I add Windows to my systemd-boot bootloader if I have separate EFI partitions?

Tags: systemd, dual-boot, boot-loader, uefi

I've just installed Arch Linux on to a new set of partitions on my Windows 8 machine.  In doing so, I created a new 512MB EFI partition for Linux to load from, leaving the existing Windows EFI partition untouched.  (I'm not sure if this was the right thing to do.)

Now systemd-boot isn't recognizing my Windows installation.  It's not a huge problem, since I can still get into the Linux bootloader from within Windows, but I'd like to be able to stick to one bootloader if possible.

How can I get systemd-boot to recognize my Windows bootloader?  Is it matter of copying files across from one partition to the other?  Or do I need to combine them in some way?

Comment: x-posted to superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/949303/can-i-add-windows-to-my-systemd-boot-bootloader-if-i-have-separate-efi-partition

Comment: You must not have several EFI System Partitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you must not have several ESPs. The one and only ESP in your system can contain any number of bootloaders in form of EFI applications.

Now you need to stick with one EFI System Partition, copy there all files from the other one and then delete the other one.

After that, re-install systemd-boot (or any other EFI boot manager of your choice) on that partition and you're all set. If we're speaking about systemd-boot (or gummiboot) specifically, then it should be able to detect the Microsoft Boot Manager on the same partition without any further configuration.

Alternatively, if your firmware is not dumb and has its own boot menu, then you can avoid installing a dedicated EFI boot manager and instead add the Linux kernel and the Microsoft Boot Manager directly to the firmware (using `efibootmgr` utility).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm terrified of messing up my system, so would you mind double checking this set of instructions I made for myself based on your answer?  1) Copy across all files from my new Linux ESP into the original Windows ESP 2) Boot from (Arch ISO) disc.  3) Remove the Linux ESP. 4) Run `parted set n boot on` for the Windows ESP 4) Rebuild the `fstab`.  5) Mount the Windows ESP (now the only ESP) to `/boot` 6) Install `systemd` on `/boot` using `pacman` 7) Reboot.  Did I miss anything or get anything the wrong way round?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 You shouldn't need to mark ESP as boot (I assume you are using GPT). Just ensure that it has correct type (`EF00` in terms of gdisk). Next, you've probably meant sd-boot and `bootctl`, not systemd and `pacman`, haven't you?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Also, you will need to reinstall `linux` (that is, the kernel package) on the new `/boot` and double-check the systemd-boot's config (`/boot/loader/*`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and it's going over my head a bit.  Should I start by `cp -r`ing everything from `/dev/sda8` (new ESP) to `/dev/sda2` (original ESP)?  And are you saying that I don't need to run `parted set 2 boot on`?  But I should still mount `sda2` to `/mnt/boot`?

Comment: And then how do I install `sd-boot` using `bootctl`?  Do I install `linux` with `bootctl` too?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Comments are not really meant for discussions; if you have questions on setting this all up, I'd be glad to answer these in [Matrix](https://matrix.org/beta) (I'm `@intelfx:intelfx.name`) or XMPP (I'm `intelfx@talk.mipt.ru`).

Comment: I realize that this is a very old thread, but it is still very useful, and my comment is a request for direct clarification of the answer here:  Why do you write "After that, reinstall systemd-boot....." Isn't it enough just to copy \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\  from the Microsoft EFI partition into the systemd-boot EFI partition, and to update entries with a windows.conf file? (Perhaps it's because reinstalling systemd-boot will automagically notice the  new EFI/Microsoft/Boot and create the .conf file by itself?